# Disable special keys on keypad

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

On my Dell keyboard there are the normal special keys (<kbd>home</kbd>, <kbd>pgdn</kbd>, etc.), arrows and then a keypad.  On the keypad these keys are duplicated in the case you press <kbd>shift</kbd>.

I'm using a program that can make use of "hotkeys" where you define what happens on the app if a certain button is pressed, and it supports modifiers.  I wanted to put all my shortcuts on the keypad since I won't be using it in this application otherwise, but I can't use many of the keys because e.g. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>keypad-2</kbd> becomes <kbd>down-arrow</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>kp-3</kbd> becomes <kbd>PageDown</kbd> and so on.

I've looked at Sharpkey, remapkey and and direct registry modification, but these tools only map a specific key.  I need to remap what happens when you press <kbd>shift</kbd> + a keypad button (while numlock is on).

Is this possible to do?